# Deploy Python Falcon app with Apache2

Tags: python-3.x, apache2, mod-wsgi, falconframework

I have developed an api using falcon framework (v1.0). Now, I want to deploy this api on apache2 server with mod_wsgi at amazon EC2 instance.

I'm running my app using wsgiref package on EC2 server.

```
import falcon
from wsgiref import simple_server

api = app = falcon.API()

class Resource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        print("i was here :(")
        if 'fields' in req.params:
            print(req.params['fields'])
            print(len(req.params['fields']))
            print(type(req.params['fields']))

res = Resource()
api.add_route('/', res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http = simple_server.make_server('0.0.0.0', 8000, app)
    http.serve_forever()
```

When I call https://example.com:8000/, I don't get any response and also my server is not getting the request.

wsgi.py file contains:

```
from test import app as application
```

I've added following lines to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess test python-path=/var/www/test/test:/var/www/test/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
 WSGIProcessGroup test
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/test/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Please explain what you've tried so far, and where you are struggling: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When using mod_wsgi it expects the WSGI application entry point to be ``application`` by default. You are using ``app`` so it will not know what your application is. You also though don't say anything about how you even configured Apache/mod_wsgi. You have done that haven't you?

Comment: Have you tried with a normal hello world Flask application? I can't even see that your current Flask application returns anything. It just drops out of the ``on_get()`` function without returning a response of any sort.

Comment: This is a falcon app. Even if nothing is returned by on_get() it should just display and empty web page, instead it give Internal server error(500).

Comment: Whoops, meant Falcon not Flask. And by returning a response, am talking about actually setting a ``status`` and ``body`` in the ``resp`` object.

Comment: And what is the details of the error in the Apache error log file?