# Deploying Python Falcon on Apache2 with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Scenario: I'm using Python Falcon framework for my REST API service. The application is initially run by `Gunicorn`.
Right now when I call https://example.com:8000/, I get a proper response that the API logic dictates.

Goal: I want to deploy it on `Apache2` along with `mod_wsgi` on my personal development server.
The API would still be running under Gunicorn, and Apache should interact with Gunicorn whenever a request is made on that end-point.

Directory structure:

```
| - abc_service
        | - abc_service
                | - __init__.py
                | - app.py
        | - wsgi.py
        | - .abc_venv
```

The source code for `app.py` looks something like this:

```
import falcon
from .abc import ABC

api = application = falcon.API() # pylint: disable=invalid-name

# Creating a unique GET resource from the ABC class
test_handler_resource = ABC() # pylint: disable=invalid-name

# Mapping the HTTP GET endpoint with the unique resource
api.add_route('/abc', test_handler_resource)

# Mapping the HTTP POST endpoint with the unique resource
api.add_route('/abc/filters', test_handler_resource)
```

In my `wsgi.py`, I have the following contents:

```
from abc_service import application
```

The configuration for Apache in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` is as follows:

```
# WSGI
WSGIDaemonProcess python-path=/home/uname/abc-service/src/abc_service/.abc_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /abc /home/uname/abc-service/src/abc_service/wsgi.py

ProxyPass /abc http://localhost:8000/abc
ProxyPassReverse /abc http://localhost:8000/abc
<Location /abc>
AuthType None
Require all granted
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</Location>
```

I can't find any helpful resource on the web regarding the same on the web that uses this combination of `Falcon`, `Gunicorn`, `mod_wsgi`, and `Apache`. So, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I appreciate your time and help. Thanks!

Comment: Similar problem as [this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464485/deploy-python-falcon-app-with-apache2). But the solution is not discussed there!

Comment: Yes, I went through that question but it wasn't really helpful.

Comment: If you are still using gunicorn and just proxying to it through Apache, you don't need mod_wsgi at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a solution that worked for me was to add the `WSGIPythonHome` path to the `Apache` configuration.

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/local/abc-service/src/abc_service/.venv
```

The final Apache configuration looks like this:

```
# At the top of the Apache Config file
WSGIPythonHome /var/local/abc-service/src/abc_service/.venv

...
...
...

# WSGI
WSGIDaemonProcess python-path=/home/uname/abc-service/src/abc_service/.abc_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /abc /home/uname/abc-service/src/abc_service/wsgi.py

ProxyPass /abc http://localhost:8000/abc
ProxyPassReverse /abc http://localhost:8000/abc
<Location /abc>
AuthType None
Require all granted
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</Location>
```